# How to store a string combination into database?

Tags: database, string, store

I have a batch's number for a product which is written in this format:

FR - LRA - 647 - 13/10/2017

While every segment has its own meaning, how can I store this as batch number for each product?

I've been thinking of using computed column as a primary key using string concatenation in BATCH_NUM table but I read that it is a bad practice in designing database.

Comment: Why can't you just store it as a single `varchar`? Do you need to perform queries on the parts separately?

Comment: @Blorgbeard So I should left the division and queries the parts for programming? Not the design?

Comment: Why would you need a computed column to serve as the primary key, when you could just have a compound column primary key, including each of the relevant columns. That should handle your data integrity issues. Also, if you want to avoid writing redundant code that concatenates the columns, put that logic in a view. It seems very much like you are overthinking a problem that was encountered by many and solved decades ago.

Comment: That depends on what you intend to do with the field. If you're not going to be using for queries like "get all batches from 2017", then you can treat it like an opaque string. If you *do* need to do that stuff, then split it up. I would not use it as a PK though. Make a surrogate PK from an autoincrementing int or GUID. Add indices on the batch fields as needed.